# The Image is shown up in the website when running it locally as a folder instead of the actual image

Tags: reactjs, image, file, bootstrap-4

im trying to upload an image on my website in the card using bootstrap but every since i run the code an image of a folder is showing up instead of the image.*I'm using React.js*

Comment: You should add more information to make it clear. The thing you are trying to explain is not clear enough.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.